# Почему выводит "2 коров", "3 коров" хотя я указал a[0:2]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [2,3,4]

s = int(input("Кол-во коров: "))

if s % 10 == 1:

    print(s,"корова")

elif s % 10 == a[0:2]:

    print(s, "коровы")

else:

    print(s, "коров")
```

Comment: замените `elif s % 10 == a[0:2]:` на `elif s % 10 in a:`

Comment: а что если число коров будет допустим не 2 а 12 ? Или по заданию строго до 10 ?

Comment: в условии результат не может быть равен срезу, т.к. срез [0:2] содержит несколько значений, а сравнить надо видимо с одним из? тогда нужно писать in.
Никита, напиши условие задачи полностью

Comment: @Leksor 2 коровы, 12 коров. Второй вариант else отрабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
a = [2,3,4]

s = int(input("Кол-во коров: "))

if s % 10 == 1:

    print(s,"корова")

elif s % 10 in a:

    print(s, "коровы")

else:

    print(s, "коров")
```

Comment: только все же наверное `elif s % 10 in a[0:3]:`

Comment: только вот a[3] нет что делать?

Comment: a[0:2] даст только [2, 3]

Comment: и вообще зачем срез тут не очень понятно

Comment: Да зачем срез вообще?

Comment: Срез это elif?.

Comment: исправил без среза

Comment: @НикитаПоляков почитайте, там не много https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

Answer (score 0):

работает в случае более 20 коров

```
a = [2,3,4]
s = int(input("Кол-во коров: "))
if s % 10 == 1:
    print(s,"корова")
elif s % 10 in a[0:3]:
    print(s, "коровы")
else:
    print(s, "коров")
```